# Time conversion in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In the following, I am getting the Timecreated time in UTC and I would like to convert it to EST.

```
$Windowsevnts += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    RDGServerName = $env:computername
    UserName = $event.Properties[0].Value
    IpAddress = [net.ipaddress]$event.Properties[1].Value
    Resource = $Event.Properties[3].Value
    TimeCreated = $event.TimeCreated
    Result = $eventtype
}
```

Comment: Sorry Same error:
Exception calling "ConvertTimeFromUtc" with "2" argument(s): "The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind property set correctly.  For example, 
when the Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be TimeZoneInfo.Local.
Parameter name: sourceTimeZone"
At line:1 char:2
+  $eventsar += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argumen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                $eventsar += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{            
                RDGServerName = $env:computername            
                UserName = $event.Properties[0].Value            
                IpAddress = [net.ipaddress]$event.Properties[1].Value            
                Resource = $Event.Properties[3].Value
                'TimeCreated in UTC' =  $event.TimeCreated         
                'TimeCreated in EST' = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($event.TimeCreated, [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id, 'Eastern Standard Time')
                Result = $eventtype            
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
$utcTime = (Get-Date $event.TimeCreated).ToUniversalTime()
$tz = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById('Eastern Standard Time')
$estTime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($utcTime, $tz)
```

Comment: Exception calling "ConvertTimeFromUtc" with "2" argument(s): "The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind property set correctly.  For example, 
when the Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be TimeZoneInfo.Local.
Parameter name: sourceTimeZone"
At line:1 char:1
+ $estTime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($utcTime, $tz)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: What version of powershell are you on and what does $tz contain when you run the code?

Comment: To me it looks like `$event.TimeCreated` might not be in [datetime] format but a string which has to casted/parseexact.

Comment: @user8172425 - see if that edit helps. I hate working with date/times by the way...[ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/) and [Supervillian Plan](https://xkcd.com/1883/)